# Surface integral to find the area of ​a cylinder between $x = y$ and $x = 2$ (in first octant)

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, surface-integrals, parametrization

Calculate the surface integral to find the area of ​​a cylinder between $x = y$ and $x = 2$ (in the first octant)

I don't know how to parametrize $x$ $y$ and $z$. And I don't understand what is the shape of the intersection between that cylinder and the planes

The parameterization that I thought is $x=x, y=2 cos \theta , z=2 sin \theta$ with $2≤x≤y$ and as we are in the first octant, $0≤ \theta ≤ {\pi}/{2}$ but as I said I'm not sure if this parameterization is correct so I would greatly appreciate the help with that and how to solve the rest of the exercise :)

Comment: Which axis is the cylinder aligned with?

Comment: the cylinder is aligned with x axis

Comment: I am trying to draw the figure, but I think some information about the surface is missing